# How to display Render Target live to HUD widget in UE4

Tags: gui, unreal-4, unreal, rendertargets, blueprints

I'm making a security camera system in Unreal Engine 4. It allows the player to 'activate' the monitor, which should display the Render Target texture or the material made from it on the HUD. However, that just doesn't work. There's just no image when I try to play it. Nothing appears on the screen. I'm using blueprints btw, not C++. And yes, I did check and make sure that it's not the part that displays the HUD that's going wrong, it's the displaying of the render target to the UI widget. To display it, i've tried using the image component in the UI widget.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I never quite figured this out(if anyone knows, still answer) but what I did instead was I created a cube that I had display the material for the render target right in front of the player camera, and had it hide/show whenever the HUD did. It looks the same as it would if it was in the HUD, but it's just a weird way to do things.

Comment: Without seeing your exact implementation, it's hard to know where the problem exists. However what you are attempting is entirely possible in UE4, as I've done a security camera myself using the method you outline. M

Comment: What about just placing the Material (that picks the render target as a diffuse color) inside UMG image ? Or if you want to use AHUD api - it can still render materials.

Answer (score 0):

This may be updated in the newer version, I applied the Material created with Render Target to the Image in the Brush settings of my Widget BP which Material Domain needs to be "User Interface".
Then the Render Target material should be shown properly in the widget even in the viewport.

[image]